# MKMapView - Adding annotations in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift, mapkit

Our application has a process that occurs when the user is zoomed in to 1500 ft. The reason this happens when so zoomed in is due to the fact that across the region where our map focuses on there are roughly 4,000 points of interest.

The problem we have with this system is that every time the region changes we have to loop through 4,000 POIs and then add the ones within the region the user is viewing.

This process freezes the whole app for 4-5 seconds and then adds the correct POIs. We explored other ways to do this and came up with a solution to stop the freezing entirely:

```
func regionDidChange(mapView: MKMapView, animated: Bool) {
    if (mapView.camera!.altitude <= 1500) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            var stopsToAdd = [StopAnnotation]()
            var stopsToRemove = [StopAnnotation]()

            // Remove old POIs
            for (var i = 0; i < self.mapView.annotations.count; i++) {
                if (self.mapView.annotations[i].isKindOfClass(StopAnnotation)) {
                    let stopAnnotation: StopAnnotation! = self.mapView.annotations[i] as StopAnnotation

                    if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(stopAnnotation.coordinate))) {
                        stopsToRemove.append(stopAnnotation)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add new POIs
            for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++) {
                if (!self.isStarredStop(self.busStops[i].atcocode)) {
                    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position))) {
                        let stop: StopAnnotation! = StopAnnotation()
                        stop.setCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)
                        stopsToAdd.append(stop)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add new POIs to map
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.mapView.removeAnnotations(stopsToRemove)
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(stopsToAdd)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I believe we're "breaking the law". After doing some research I think it is frowned upon to do such processes in another thread. However even if I were to ignore that advice sometimes crashes do occur.

The crash occurs on line 9:

```
if (self.mapView.annotations[i].isKindOfClass(StopAnnotation)) {
```

Error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil'`

Could anyone please help me come up with an alternative solution to ensure the application runs smoothly as described above without crashing?

Comment: You should perform annotation related stuff in your main UI thread, not the background thread because the annotation adding and removing are UI updates, you should do these in main UI thread.

Comment: @ztan Doing those changes in the main UI thread means that the application freezes for 5-10 seconds, unless I am misunderstanding? By main UI thread do you mean just performing the code normally and not inside `dispatch_async`?

Comment: If you try to do API request, then you have to perform in background thread, but the thing you are doing now are all UI related, so you can just do them in main UI thread. Also search your file, see if you call `addObject` method anywhere.

Comment: Your problem is more to do with how you are storing your POIs, it's inefficient to have to iterate over 4000 on every pan just to find which ones are in the region, I think you should reconsider how you model this data and think of more efficient ways to manage this data.

Comment: @Jeff Could you give an example of another model? From my programming knowledge entirely I don't have any clue how this could be done another way

Comment: @Jeff Bearing in mind that we are not able to dynamically pull from a web service (eg sending screen coords and getting POIs back), one of the requirements is that this is done from memory

Comment: An approach I used an old app, maybe not ideal either (but was actually suggested by Apple), is to have all the POIs on an additional MapView that has frame of CGRectZero. You can then grab the POIs from that map and add/remove them to your MapView that is actually visible on screen as you pan.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe this is synchronization problem between threads. On background thread you are trying to access annotations directly from map view, and at the same time on main thread you are adding/removing them from map view.

Change the first for-loop to:

```
// Remove old POIs

NSArray annotations = [elf.mapView.annotations copy];
MKMapRect visibleMapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;

for (var i = 0; i < annotations.count; i++) {
    if (annotations[i].isKindOfClass(StopAnnotation)) {
        let stopAnnotation: StopAnnotation! = annotations[i] as StopAnnotation

        if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(stopAnnotation.coordinate))) {
            stopsToRemove.append(stopAnnotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code can and will also crash at the [self.mapView.annotations copy] statement with the same exception as the question. And therefore not a working solution (although it would likely crash less times)